# I need to add additional fields to sample export csv file on my Magento 2.3

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I need to add additional fields to my Magento sample export template like including package, package prices, etc. I don't know how to do that. Can someone walk me through? Thanks in advance
Destiny

Answer (score 0):

The sample export files come from pre-generated/static csv files, for example in case of products it comes from `Magento_ImportExport::Files/Sample/catalog_product.csv`

Create a new module copy the sample file from `/vendor/magento/module-import-export/Files/Sample/catalog_product.csv` add new attributes into `additional_attributes` column, override the `Download` controller `Adminhtml\Import\Download` and that's it.